# Parse YouTube data string in, into a Video object

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsonp, youtube-data-api, javadoc

URL to the data I am using: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=AU&videoCategoryId=15&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I am currently developing this Intelli J Java command line application that can detect the YouTube Trending Topics. However, I am in need of help in writing some code on trying to  Parse YouTube data string in, into a Video object. This is some code I have done but am unsure if its right for doing a Parse on a YouTube data string:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;

public class YouTubeTrender {

    public static void test1() throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Performing Test 1");
        String filename = "data/youtubedata_15_50.json";
        int expectedSize = 50;

        System.out.println("Testing the file: " + filename);
        System.out.println("Expecting size of: " + expectedSize);

        // Read data
        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new FileInputStream(filename));
        JsonObject jobj = jsonReader.readObject();

        // read the values of the item field
        JsonArray items = jobj.getJsonArray("items");

        System.out.println("Size of input: " + items.size());
        System.out.println("Sucess: " + (expectedSize == items.size()));


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("YouTube Trender Application");

        test1();

    }
}
```

I should mention before I forget the code here some how has the JsonReader, JsonObject, Json.createReader, readObject, JsonArray, getJsonArray, json in the import section above is all red coloured text as an error and some how wants me to create a class.

Comment: Do you want to convert a URL into a Video? So you want to download it?

Comment: I do apologies if i have confused you but that is where I am getting the YouTube Data from, but I put it up there if its needed for Parsing. Basically my question is how to Parse YouTube data string in, into a Video object. Hopefully that makes it clear

Comment: So you want to parse the video metadata to a Video object containing that metadata no?

Comment: Yes that would be correct

Comment: This application is for detecting YouTube Trending Topics

Comment: Okay, I understand now. This can be done via a library called Jackson. I will post an answer now. Could you please send the contents of the JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a JSON String to a class using a library called Jackson. First of all, you must import this library. If you are using Maven you can add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to create your `Video` class that will hold the data. Jackson maps the every key of the JSON String to a class Field with the same name. For example:

```
{
    "hello": "hi",
    "name": "alex"
}
```

Then if you map that JSON to a class called Greeting:

```
public class Greeeting {
    private String hello;
    private String name;

    // The class must have getters and setters
    public String getHello() {
        return this.hello;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you map the string to Greeting.class an instance of Greeting will be created containting `hi` in `hello` field and `alex` in `name` field.

To do this mapping you can do:

```
public Greeting parseGreeting(String json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(json, Greeting.class);
}
```

Instead of a string you can also pass a file as the first parameter.

Now you have to implement your `Video.class` depending on which fields you JSON has.

Comment: Okay. I have a video class already. In fact I will tell you my classes now that I currently have. I have  YouTubeTrender being the main class. Then my other classes that are not the main are YouTubeVideo, YouTubeDataParser and YouTubeDataParser Exception. So my question is now where would I implement  the Jackson library?

Comment: On YoutubeTrender class, where you read the JSON data from the file into `jobj`. You could do: `YoutubeVideo video = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jobj.toString(), YoutubeVideo.class);`. Remember that you `YoutubeVideo` class must have the same fields names and data structures as the JSON data values and keys.

Comment: I forgot to check with you what is Maven out of curiosity?

Comment: Maven is a building tool for Java (C#, Scala and Ruby too) projects developed by the Apache Software Foundation. It makes it easy to specify a building routine and it makes it even easier to import dependencies from its central repository. You can find more info about Maven go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven.

If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as a solution to this question.

Comment: For sure I will mark it as answered but how can i mark it as answered? Also If i have any further question how can I get in contact with you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers If you need help with other things just post them in stackoverflow so that I am not the only one that will help you.

Comment: For sure. Thanks again